# How to load a mycred hook from a plugin?

Tags: customization, hooks

I've created a hook for mycred following [this tutorial](http://mycred.me/support/tutorials/how-to-make-your-custom-hook/).

I added the code to the `function.php`, and I am now wondering how to call it from my plugin?

I have no clue, and the tutorials that I've found also offer no advice.

Any advice?

My cred is a plugin that once installs, awards the users with points for their interaction with the site. More info can be found. [here](http://codex.mycred.me/).

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. What's a *mycred* hook? Please add all relevant information into your question, to make it easier for others to help you. If the link goes down, then it's not possible to know what you're asking for. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the code used in the plugin?  Assuming you have activated the plugin and include any files with relevant code in them, the implementation should be the same.

Comment: @birgire my bad, I thought that mycred was one of those things everyone knew about. Shows how little I know about wordpress! will update.

Comment: @RachelBaker hello, it's a demo hook they have in the site. I was just confused about how I was going to include it in my plugin. Eventually, I stopped over thinking and added this code where I loaded my page. $mycredhook = new my_demo_hook_class();
 do_action( 'play_game', $mycredhook); Not sure, if it's the right way, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I did this in the function of my plugin where I was loading my game,

$mycredhook = new my_demo_hook_class();
do_action( 'play_game', $mycredhook);

Not sure if this is the correct way to go, but it worked.